# Python Selenium Unable to find an element inside Frameset > Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I find the highlighted element in the following html structure.

[Target element highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9icA.png)

This is the code that I'm using.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Edge()
browser.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
browser.get(url) # aspx page

browser.find_element_by_id("LoginBtn").click()

browser.find_element_by_id("ReportingMenuName").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("EndpointDataExportSubmenuName").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("EndpointDataExportMenuItem").click()

browser.switch_to_default_content()

browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id("main"))

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(\
                       (By.ID, "ct100_PageBody_OkButton")))
element.click()
```

When I run the code I get this error when it reaches the last 2 lines of code:
TimeoutException

If I change the last 2 lines of code for this, then I get another error.

```
browser.find_element_by_id("ct100_PageBody_OkButton").click()
```

NoSuchElementException: No such element

Comment: Instead of using find by id , you can try using **find by selector** with value **"input[id$='OkButton']"** .. Since, you are able to switch to frame with id = main without running in to exception and you are getting No such element , most probably the id is dynamic and i am making a wild guess that ct100 part is changing...consider sharing page url if it's a public site . The suggested selector will match input element whose id ends with OkButton.

Comment: one option is sleep (2-3 seconds depends on latency) b/w switching to frame and expected condition element will solve this. I also faced this issue, but could not find better solution.

Comment: similar question asked and anwered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677267/how-to-wait-for-a-selenium-frame-to-load-before-waiting-for-an-element-to-load

Comment: Nish26, you suggestion to user find by css selector worked. Thank you. I wonder how you got to the conclusion that the element id was dynamic? When you say dynamic is because it could change in different sessions? When I inspect the element with different browsers it always show the same id.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you need to consider :

- While you access/login to a url *Selenium's* focus is on the [**Top Level Browsing Context**](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/browsers.html#windows). So before switching to any *frame* you don't need to `switch_to_default_content()`. Hence you can omit the line :

  ```
  browser.switch_to_default_content()
  ```
- While you switch to frame through `switch_to.frame()` induce *WebDriverWait* with the clause [**`frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it) for the *frame* to be available for switching as follows :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"main")))
  ```
- Within the frame once you identify the element moving ahead as you are invoking `click()` so instead of `expected_conditions` as `presence_of_element_located` you need to use [**`element_to_be_clickable`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='buttontext' and contains(@id,'_PageBody_OkButton')]"))).click()
  ```

Comment: DebajanB, thank for your answer. I tried the changes you suggested. You were right about no need to "switch_to_default_content()". Also, the change to "EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it" worked; but the selection of the element didn't work. How ever, when I used "find_by_css_selector", like Nish26 suggested, then it worked.

Comment: @M.Rod Check out my updated answer and let me know the status.