# How to address "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: target frame detached" using Selenium through C#

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, iframe, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

Since chrome updated to version 80 I started getting:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: target frame detached
```

error from the chrome webdriver, when trying to switch frames.

Even `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` doesn't work. It throws a timeout.

Is there any way to avoid or recover from this exception?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: target frame detached
```

...implies that a resultant *HttpServerResponseInfo* was **net::HTTP_NOT_FOUND**.

---

### Details

As per the discussion [Some error codes are not standard compliant](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2552) there are some Chrome-specific error codes which still exists and most clients will treat them as **`unknown error`**. These error codes are:

- **`target frame detached`**
- **`chrome not reachable`**
- **`disconnected`**
- **`forbidden`**
- **`no such execution context`**
- **`tab crashed`**

This issue was addressed through the [bug](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/97fe5556deaed6d34e587dbe57cdf12df4f95b97) / [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/97fe5556deaed6d34e587dbe57cdf12df4f95b97) and the current status is **ToBeReleased**.

---

### Deep Dive

The error *target frame detached* is defined in [case kTargetDetached](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/97fe5556deaed6d34e587dbe57cdf12df4f95b97/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/status.cc#75) where `case kTargetDetached` is defined in [http_handler.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/server/http_handler.cc#993) and occurs when the *HttpServerResponseInfo* contains `HTTP_NOT_FOUND` as follows:

```
void HttpHandler::HandleCommand(
    const net::HttpServerRequestInfo& request,
    const std::string& trimmed_path,
    const HttpResponseSenderFunc& send_response_func) {
  base::DictionaryValue params;
  std::string session_id;
  CommandMap::const_iterator iter = command_map_->begin();
  while (true) {
    if (iter == command_map_->end()) {
      if (w3cMode(session_id, session_thread_map_)) {
    PrepareResponse(
        trimmed_path, send_response_func,
        Status(kUnknownCommand, "unknown command: " + trimmed_path),
        nullptr, session_id, true);
      } else {
    std::unique_ptr<net::HttpServerResponseInfo> response(
        new net::HttpServerResponseInfo(net::HTTP_NOT_FOUND));
    response->SetBody("unknown command: " + trimmed_path, "text/plain");
    send_response_func.Run(std::move(response));
      }
      return;
    }
    if (internal::MatchesCommand(
        request.method, trimmed_path, *iter, &session_id, &params)) {
      break;
    }
    ++iter;
  }
```

and most possibly the reason in your case is [kTargetDetached](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/server/http_handler.cc#1171):

```
case kTargetDetached:
  response.reset(new net::HttpServerResponseInfo(net::HTTP_NOT_FOUND));
  break;
```

---

### Solution

To switch [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s **focus** within an `<iframe>` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it* as follows:

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.CssSelector("iframe#twitter-widget-0")));
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//fieldset[@id='twitter-widget-0']")));
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to wait for a frame to load before locating an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677267/how-to-wait-for-a-frame-to-load-before-locating-an-element/49686113#49686113)
- [How to locate and click on an element which is nested within multiple frame and frameset through Selenium using Webdriver and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798937/how-to-locate-and-click-on-an-element-which-is-nested-within-multiple-frame-and/50813825#50813825)

---

### Outro

[Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)

Comment: above solution is not working for latest chrome version 81 and it did not work for 80.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. Try to update the chromedriver version 80.0.3987.16 with selenium. Switching to iFrame should work fine. It works for me.