# Unable to locate element using Selenium Chromedriver when it's there in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get my program to click on a button however I receive errors.

My code:

```
driver.FindElementById("couponsinc-gallery-selectall").Click();
```

Error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#\couponsinc\-gallery\-selectall"}
```

Here is the code of the button on the page:

```
<div class="selectall">
            <input type="checkbox" class="selectall-chk" id="couponsinc-gallery-selectall">
            <label for="couponsinc-gallery-selectall">Clip All</label>
        </div>
```

I've also tried my using `FindElementByClassName` but nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) with text as *Clip All* an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return scrollBy(0, 800);");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.CssSelector("iframe[title='Coupons']"));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input.selectall-chk#couponsinc-gallery-selectall"))).Click();
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return scrollBy(0, 800);");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[@title='Coupons']"));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class='selectall-chk' and @id='couponsinc-gallery-selectall']"))).Click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: keyfoods]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [How to wait for a frame to load before locating an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677267/how-to-wait-for-a-frame-to-load-before-locating-an-element/49686113#49686113)

Comment: I've tried this and have gotten this error: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'Timed out after 20 seconds' with the same inner exception: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element, here is the website: https://www.keyfood.com/store/keyFood/en/printable-coupons, you can test it for yourself, it's the "Clip All" button near the bottom of the page.

Comment: @africohal Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: This time I got this exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'Timed out after 20 seconds' followed by this inner exception: InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified which occured on this line: new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("//input.selectall-chk#couponsinc-gallery-selectall"))).Click();

Comment: @africohal My bad, it was a typo, fixed it, please check now both the locators and let me know the status.

Comment: Awesome! The solution seems to work and I've marked it as the soltuion but I still don't understand why my simple code doesn't work as it definitely worked for a different button on a different website.

Comment: @africohal I tried my best to provide you all the reference in the form on embedded links. Happy coding